# TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'tuple' for Python

Tags: python

1) I have two lists of equal length, grades and Names.
2) I am trying to have these two lists paired so that names will move in coordination with grades ranked from highest (/100) to lowest

Entering this function in the IDE shell:

```
>>> grades, Names = zip(*sorted(zip(grades, Names), key = str.lower, reverse = True))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 2):

`sorted` feeds the *entire* argument to the key function. If you're trying to sort a list of 2-tuples, as you'd get from `zip()`, you need to specifically target the string element. You can do this with a lambda function:

```
# sort the list by reverse-alphabetical order of names, keeping grades and names together
grades, Names = zip(*sorted(
    zip(grades, Names), 
    key = lambda tup: tup[1].lower(), # call .lower() on the 'name' part of the tuple
    reverse = True))
```

But if you're just trying to sort by grades, then you don't actually need to provide a key in this case. When `sorted` tries to sort 2-tuples without a key, its default behavior is to compare the first element of the tuple, and *only if it's equal*, compare the second element of the tuple, and so on. So, this:

```
grades, Names = zip(*sorted(zip(grades, Names), reverse=True)
```

should output corresponding `grades` and `Names`, in order from highest grade to lowest grade, with ties broken by name sorted in reverse-alphabetical order.